# Two different Audio file to be played with Two different buttons

Tags: javascript

There are Two buttons both named Buttons, I want each one to play a different audio file, how to do that in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what files you want to play but I will use `one.mp3` and `two.mp3`. 
And I will also use buttons. (`<button onclick="oneBtn()">Button 1</button>` and `<button onclick="twoBtn()">Button 2</button>`)
JavaScript Code:

```
    function playFile(dir){
      var audioFile = new Audio(dir);
      audioFile.play();
    }
    function oneBtn(){
      playFile("one.mp3");
    }
    function twoBtn(){
      playFile("two.mp3");
    }
```

HTML code:

```
    <button onclick="oneBtn()">Button 1</button>
    <button onclick="twoBtn()">Button 2</button>
```

If you click `Button 1` it will play `one.mp3`. And it also happens in Button 2.